# How to use .filter()/.get() to see whether a value is in an external model for validation in Django?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I made a form from a model (EmployeeWorkAreaLog) where the user can enter their Employee # and once they press Enter/Leave, it searches a separate model (Salesman) in the db to make sure this person is a valid employee, if not, a message would pop up from the html side saying it's not valid.

Now, I'm trying to add another constraint, such that, if the employee is not in the 'WF' team then it would also give an error, and say to contact a manager. I tried doing it from the forms, but I keep getting this error:

`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Salesman'`

and according to the traceback, it comes from `if Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number).count():`

Why is this error occurring? Is there a more efficient/better way to check the employee's team?

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_number
```

The part where I filter it so only employee #'s from Salesman is under the widget attrs as shown below

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')

    def clean_employee_number(self):
        employee_number = self.cleaned_data.get('employee_number')

        if Salesman.objects.filter(id=employee_number).team is 'WF':
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Employee not valid, please contact manager"))
        return employee_number
```

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        elif 'leave_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

Comment: As the error says, `employee_number` is (despite the name) an instance of Salesman already. You don't need to query the database at all.

Comment: `Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number).count()` does not make much sense either, since you call `.count()` on a `Salesman` object, not on a `QuerySet`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oops yes, that was my bad. I initially had filter, not get.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but, how would I go about accesing the "team" field that is within Salesman to check it? employee_number is a foreignkey of salesman, but I can't seem to be able to get to one it points to to check the team.

Comment: Why not just `employee_number.team`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() return a single Salesman object and filter() returns a query set.

To check if salesman exists with the given employee_number and team 'WF' with get():

```
def clean_employee_number(self):
    employee_number = self.cleaned_data.get('employee_number')

    try:
        salesman = Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number, team='WF')
    except Salesman.DoesNotExist:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Employee not valid, please contact manager"))
    return employee_number
```

with filter():

```
  def clean_employee_number(self):
    employee_number = self.cleaned_data.get('employee_number')

    salesman = Salesman.objects.filter(id=employee_number, team='WF').first()
    if not salesman:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Employee not valid, please contact manager"))
    return employee_number
```